# Show the following in the ring of polynomials in $x$, $y$ and $z$ with coefficients in $F$.

Tags: ring-theory, polynomial-rings

> Let $F$ be a field. Prove that in the ring of polynomials in $x$, $y$ and $z$ with coefficients in $F$ $:$
>
> $\left (Y^2 Z^2, XYZ \right ) = \left (Y \right ) \cap \left (Z \right ) \cap \left (X,Y \right ).$

Any polynomial in
$\left (Y^2 Z^2, XYZ \right )$ is of the form $p(x,y,z)y^2 z^2 + q(x,y,z) xyz$. Which can be written in three forms

(1) $y(p(x,y,z)yz^2 + q(x,y,z)xz)$ i.e. $yP(x,y.z)$ where $P(x,y,z) = p(x,y,z)yz^2 + q(x,y,z)xz.$

(2) $z(p(x,y,z)y^2 z + q(x,y,z)xy)$ i.e. $zQ(x,y,z)$ where $Q(x,y,z) = p(x,y,z)y^2 z + q(x,y,z)xy.$

(3) $y(p(x,y,z)yz^2) + x (q(x,y,z)yz)$ i.e. $xR(x,y,z) + yS(x,y,z)$ where $R(x,y,z) = y(p(x,y,z)yz^2)$ and $S(x,y,z) = x(q(x,y,z)yz).$

From (1), (2) and (3) it is clear that $\left (Y^2 Z^2, XYZ \right ) \subseteq \left (Y \right ) \cap \left (Z \right ) \cap \left (X,Y \right ).$

But how can I do the reverse part. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $(Y) \cap (Z) \cap (X,Y)$ simplifies to $(Y) \cap (Z)$, since $(Y) \subset (X,Y)$, and then further simplifies to $(YZ)$.

Thus, the reverse inclusion holds if and only if $YZ \in (Y^2Z^2,XYZ)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{But}\;\;&YZ \in (Y^2Z^2,XYZ)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&YZ=aY^2Z^2+bXYZ,\;\text{for some}\;a,b \in F[X,Y,Z]\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1 = aYZ + bX\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1 = 0\qquad\text{[by substituting $X=Y=Z=0$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that the reverse inclusion doesn't hold.

Comment: It was given in assignment. I think the correct version is $\left (YZ, XYZ \right ) = \left (Y \right ) \cap \left (Z \right ) \cap \left (X,Y \right )$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So as an assignment problem how would I treat it?

Comment: You disprove it!

Comment: I think for instance I may take $xyz+yz \in  \left (Y \right ) \cap \left (Z \right ) \cap \left (X,Y \right )$ but $xyz + yz \notin \left (Y^2 Z^2, XYZ \right )$. Please verify it.

Comment: Why not just $yz$?

Comment: Yeah you are right! Thanks.

Comment: But it's also the case that $xyz + yz \notin \left (y^2 z^2, xyz \right )$

Comment: For your assignment, you should prove the forward inclusion (+1, by the way), and disprove the reverse inclusion. Also, if you feel like it, you can give proofs for the (likely) corrected version.

Comment: Thank you for cooperating me.